# Difference Chart using Dimple.js

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

Is there an easy way to create a difference chart using dimple? I'm looking to create something similar to this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3894205/.

Thanks

Comment: that would be neat to do. I have not seen an example of this in dimple. The closest I have seen is the horizontal stacked line chart http://dimplejs.org/examples_viewer.html?id=lines_horizontal_stacked . However the difference between the lines is not being colored in.

Comment: It probably is possible, but it will involve hacking the data of an area chart and is certainly not straight "out of the box".  If I were you I'd use raw d3 for that one.

Answer (score 0):

> I know this was asked 2 years ago, maybe someone is still interested :-)

A way to do this with dimple is to transform your 2 series (say A and B) into 3 series:

- a serie that draws the **lower line**: its values are `min(A,B)`
- a serie that draws the **upper line when A > B** and fills with **green**: its values are `max(A-B,0)`
- a serie that draws the **upper line when A < B** and fills with **red**: its values are `max(B-A,0)`

Then you stack all 3 and use `dimple.plot.area` for the last 2 to have the fill-in effect.

We can make a working example if you provide your code and data.